# Calling a function before Defining it in Java

Tags: java, methods, function-declaration

I have noticed that you can call a function in java before defining it, just like Javascript. Now I know that Javascript supports function hoisting because of which it is possible to do so, but what about Java, for ex

```java
public class Sample_class {
    

    public void sample_meth1()
    {
        sample_meth2(); //calling before defining
    }

    public void sample_meth2() //Function Definition
    {

    }
}
```

The same goes for main method, where you can call a method before it has been declared and defined. Why and How?

I was expecting a compile time error, but it executed successfully.

Comment: Check out forward referencing: https://coderanch.com/wiki/660181/Referencing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You cannot call the main method before it is defined. You're also not actually calling any functions before definition, since the class definition and all function names are compiled before method bodies

Comment: one of the advantages of compiled code: the compiler *can* work with more than one pass, that is, it *can* read the code multiple times if necessary (for example first pass get all [method] declarations; second pass solve all method calls; ...) || BTW this is also valid for class/instance variables, these can be declared at the very end of a class

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the order of the methods doesn't matter. You can call a method from any other method, even though one method is defined before the other.